# How to force client to download files locally over SMB instead of holding the file open

Tags: windows, mac-osx, filesystems, server-message-block, file-server

Is there a way client or server side MacOS and Windows. To force a client to download files locally, rather than to hold the file open when being read?

Similar to how Chrome OS does this.

Comment: Server-Side: nothing. That's not how SMB works.
However you should take a look at [Work Folders](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/work-folders/work-folders-overview) for Windows.

Comment: It looks like Work Folders are a solution for offline File Synchronization. My goal is just prevent people from creating file locks. I've seen recommendations to use IIS to create a website or to use FTP, but I'm looking for a way to do this using native explorer/finder etc. Thank you for your response.